# Why the existence of such an operator implies that $\mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^d)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\Omega )$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We have the following theorem : suppose $\Omega \mathbb R^n$ is of class $\mathcal C^1$ with a bounded boundary. There exists an extension operator
$$P:W^{1,p}(\Omega )\longrightarrow W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^d)$$
such that for all $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega )$, 
$$Pu|_\Omega =u,\quad \|Pu\|_{L^p(\Omega )}\leq C\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega )},\quad \text{and}\quad \|Pu\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega )}\leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega )}.$$

1) First of all, is $P$ continuous?

2) Why does it imply that $\mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^d)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\Omega )$ ?

I recall that $\mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^d)$ mean functions that are $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^d)$ which have compact support.

Comment: There are a lot of typos in this post. First of all, what did you mean to say instead of "bounded boundary"?

Comment: For example $\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1>0\}$ has for boundary $\{(0,x_2)\mid x_2\in \mathbb R\}$ that is not bounded whereas the circle has a bounded boundary (I think) @UmbertoP.

Comment: Does $\Omega$ need to be bounded too?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is the complement of a closed ball, then its boundary is bounded but $\Omega$ is not. So $\Omega$ does not need to be bounded.

Comment: You need to know two things: for (1) that $P$ is linear; for (2) that $C_c^1(\mathbb R^d)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^d)$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to my knowledge, the operator $P$ you wrote there is called the *extension* operator.

The existence of extension operator depends on the geometric property of domain. The most common requirement could be "the boundary of $\Omega$ is Lipschitz".

For 1, note that $P$ is a linear operator, so it is continuous.

For 2, I guess the argument here is since $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^d)$, and hence by using extension operator, you can prove that the density result in $\Omega$.

You may look for some Sobolev space book about more information of extension operator. For example, this [book](https://www.crcpress.com/Measure-Theory-and-Fine-Properties-of-Functions/Evans-Gariepy/p/book/9780849371578) is good.